# System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 14: Trigger.FieldUpdate: line 17, column 1

Tags: apex, trigger

I am Getting this type of error:

> Error:Apex trigger FieldUpdate caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: FieldUpdate: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 14: Trigger.FieldUpdate: line 17, column 1

My Code:

```
trigger FieldUpdate on Account (before insert, after update) 
{  
Integer nextSize;
List<String> pickListValuesIntoList  = new  List<String>();
List <Schema.PicklistEntry> pickListValues = Account.Status_c__c.getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
for(Account Acc: trigger.new) 
{   
    for(Schema.PicklistEntry pi: pickListValues)
    {  
        pickListValuesIntoList.add(pi.getLabel());  
    }
    system.debug('pickListValuesIntoList:'+pickListValuesIntoList); 
    if(Acc.Status_c__c!=trigger.oldmap.get(Acc.id).Status_c__c && trigger.oldmap.get(Acc.id).Status_c__c!=null )
    {
        for(Integer nextSize=1;nextSize<pickListValues.size();nextSize++)
        {
            if(Acc.Status_c__c==pickListValuesIntoList[nextSize+1])
            {
                if(trigger.oldmap.get(acc.id).Status_c__c==pickListValuesIntoList[nextSize])
                {
                    Acc.Status_c__c=pickListValuesIntoList[nextSize+1];
                }
                else
                {
                    Acc.Status_c__c.adderror('Account status cant change'); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Help me on this how to reslove it!

Thanks.

Comment: why you have kept " for(Schema.PicklistEntry pi: pickListValues) " for loop inside the " for(Account Acc: trigger.new)  " for loop .  any specific Reason ?

Comment: And one more thing is you have used "before insert" in trigger , Before insert does contain trigger.oldmap.   Look at where to used old and new map, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm

Comment: @NITHESHK to use Adderror method i have done like that.

Comment: @ NITHESH K perfect comment , we  should not use like that, for(Schema.PicklistEntry pi: pickListValues) " for loop inside the " for(Account Acc: trigger.new) " for loop , trigger.oldMap is not used in before insert trigger, make sure to modify the code

Comment: @salesforce also add little brief description about your code, what you want to achieve in this code  and when you want (while inserting or updating) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify your code as below, But i have no idea about your logic going to do.

```
trigger FieldUpdate on Account (before insert, after update) {  
    Integer nextSize;
    List<String> pickListValuesIntoList  = new  List<String>();
    List <Schema.PicklistEntry> pickListValues = Account.Status_c__c.getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
    for(Schema.PicklistEntry pi: pickListValues) 
        pickListValuesIntoList.add(pi.getLabel());  
    if (Trigger.isInsert) {
        // your insert trigger.
    }
    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {              
        for(Account Acc: trigger.new) {           
            if(Acc.Status_c__c!=trigger.oldmap.get(Acc.id).Status_c__c && trigger.oldmap.get(Acc.id).Status_c__c!=null ) {                
                for(Integer nextSize=0;nextSize<pickListValues.size();nextSize++)   {                    
                    if(Acc.Status_c__c==pickListValuesIntoList[nextSize])  {
                        if(trigger.oldmap.get(acc.id).Status_c__c==pickListValuesIntoList[nextSize])
                        { Acc.Status_c__c=pickListValuesIntoList[nextSize];}
                        else
                        {  Acc.Status_c__c.adderror('Account status cant change'); }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My trigger fuctinalty is selecting picklist values one by one.now List index out of bounds:  have been sloved.but picklist values are not going in series like a->b->c->d. it is saving first value only

Comment: { Acc.Status_c__c=pickListValuesIntoList[nextSize]; Break ;}  Just add break statement

Comment: Break statement is worked for you ?

Comment: No bro i have done like this  for(Integer nextSize=0;nextSize<pickListValues.size()-1;nextSize++).

Comment: Okay.... Still i am wearied why -1 is need..Any way work fine right, Good.

Answer (score 1):

On the specific error, this code loops right up to the last element in the array and then indexes one element beyond the end in `[nextSize+1]`:

```
for(Integer nextSize=1;nextSize<pickListValues.size();nextSize++)
{
    if(Acc.Status_c__c==pickListValuesIntoList[nextSize+1])
```

so you need to rethink that logic.

(As people have commented, there are other problems. Also maps could be used to avoid the loop inside a loop which can cause performance/governor limit problems.)